# External work required to move charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-fields, charge

[image]

There are 2 charged which are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign, and they are equidistant from the vertical axis AB. The voltage at both A and B would be 0.

If I introduce a new charge at point A, what would be the external work required to get it to point B?

In a case like this, I know that the electric field generated by the blue and red charges would be perpendicular to the movement along the vertical axis, so the work done by the electric field is 0.

However, to move the charge from A to B, would there be any external work required (even though the charge is moving along an equipotential surface)?

Comment: Let's say the charge moves, doesn't it gain kinetic energy? Where is that energy coming from if the work is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly note, the electric field will be perpendicular to the line **AB**  and will not do any work on the test charge if it moves along that path. But, there must be some constraint to keep it on that path.

Assuming there is some constraint, let's now move the test charge from point A toward point B. To get the charge moving, you must do work (call it $W_1$) on it, exerting a force toward B and it moves that direction ($W_1>0$).  The charge is now moving along the line with kinetic energy $K=W_1$, and you want it to stop at point B. Again you do work on it ($W_2$), exerting a force opposite its velocity, so the kinetic energy decreases to zero, so $W_2=-K=-W_1$.

The net work done by your outside force in moving the charge **from rest** at point A to **rest** at point B is zero: $$W_{\mathrm{net}}=W_1+W_2=W_1+(-W_1)=0.$$

On the other hand, if the charge doesn't stop at point B, the net work from A to B is not zero.